# Generating reports for junit when test methods run individually

Tags: java, ant, junit, jenkins

I have a Java project with JUnit tests which I run on Jenkins using Ant. Following various tutorials online, I made it possible for all the tests to run individually.

My **build.xml** looks like this:

```
<target name="run_junit" depends="compile, ensure-test-name"
                                  description="Run JUnit tests">
    <echo message="Execute Test" />
    <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" fork="yes">
        <sysproperty key="tests" value="${tests}"/>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <pathelement path="bin"/>
        </classpath>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
      <batchtest>
         <fileset dir="src">
             <include name="${test}.java"/>
         </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

This, together with my own Runner and Filter classes, and `@RunWith` annotations, means that I can run an individual test within an individual class like this:

```
ant run_junit -Dtest=ClassWithTests -Dtests=testMethod
```

This works perfectly fine, in Jenkins as well, and I am also able to run the tests in parallel. The problem I have is that the reports for each class get overwritten after each method is run.

For example, the above command will produce a file **TEST-ClassWithTests.xml** with information about the result and output of *testMethod*. However, if I then run

```
ant run_junit -Dtest=ClassWithTests -Dtests=anotherTestMethod
```

the **TEST-ClassWithTests.xml** file will get overwritten and will only contain information about the result and output of *anotherTestMethod*.

---

---

So my question is: How do I make JUnit generate separate test reports for each method? And is there some way of nicely combining them so that they display well on Jenkins? I would ask whether it is possible to append methods to an existing JUnit report, but these tests are meant to be running in parallel, so that would probably not be helpful.

Comment: What states that the file will be called `TEST-ClassWithTests.xml`? Find that and figure out how to append a timestamp or something, so every time the test will be run a unique timestamp will be applied etc.

Comment: @CeilingGecko - Yes, I have been searching for that yesterday and today, with no luck. There's information about concatenating the .xml files into one report, but I can't find anything about naming the original test summaries...

Comment: Could you use the `<test>` element instead of the `<batchtest>`? It allows you to specify a dedicated test-result-file (attribute: `outfile`) and even allows you to select the test-methods to be executed (attribute: `methods`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `<test>` instead of `<batchtest>` as this allows to specify a dedicated output-file. Like this:

```
  <test name="${test}" outfile="TEST-${test}-${tests}"/>
```

Since ant 1.8.2 this even allows you to run individual test methods through the attribute `methods`:

```
  <test name="${test}" outfile="TEST-${test}-${tests}" methods="${tests}"/>
```

This might help you getting rid of your custom runner.

Jenkins should be able to collect all report files properly and combine them into a single view.

Comment: Oh, somehow I missed the fact that there is the `methods` attribute and spent ages trying to get the methods to run using custom Filters and Runners. Everything works like a charm now, thanks.